# Why isn't my delete method not deleting the data after passing delete method declared in Dao interface?

Tags: android, android-room, android-mvvm

So, after I show the saved data in the form of Recyclerview I am trying to delete a specifc position data after click listener on imageView declared in recyclerview class by calling delete method declared in Dao interface. I am following MVVM pattern. But when i click on the imageView no action happens.

recyclerview.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:background="@drawable/rounded_cardview"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:paddingStart="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_marginStart="30dp"
        android:text="@string/word1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/word2"
        android:textColor="#FFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        style="@style/word_title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageDelete"
        android:src="@drawable/baseline_delete_24"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

second.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".SecondActivity">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_button"
        tools:listitem="@layout/recyclerview"
        android:padding="10dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab1"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/add_word"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The secondactivity.kt

```
class SecondActivity:AppCompatActivity() {

    lateinit var binding: SecondBinding
    val cardViewmodel:  CardViewmodel by viewModels{
        WordViewModelFactory((application as CardsApplication).repository)
    }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
         binding = SecondBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
         setContentView(binding.root)

        val adapter = CardListAdapter()
        binding.recyclerview1.adapter = adapter
        binding.recyclerview1.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)

        cardViewmodel.allWords.observe(this) { cardPairs ->

            for (cardpair in cardPairs) {
                 adapter.submitList(cardPairs)
            }

        }

        val inflator = getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE) as LayoutInflater
        val view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.recyclerview,null)

        val imageDelete = view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageDelete)

        imageDelete.setOnClickListener {

            // Get the position of the clicked item
            val position = binding.recyclerview1.getChildAdapterPosition(view)

            // Get the CardPair object from the adapter using the position
            val cardPair = adapter.currentList[position]

            // Call the delete() method on your CardViewmodel to delete the CardPair from the database
            cardViewmodel.deleteCards(cardPair)

            // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
            adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

        }
    }
}
```

Cardviewmodel.kt

```
class CardViewmodel(private val repository:CardPairRepository) : ViewModel() {

    // Using LiveData and caching what allWords returns has several benefits:
    // - We can put an observer on the data (instead of polling for changes) and only update the
    //   the UI when the data actually changes.
    // - Repository is completely separated from the UI through the ViewModel.
    val allWords: LiveData<List<CardPair>> = repository.allWords.asLiveData()

    /**
     * Launching a new coroutine to insert the data in a non-blocking way
     */
    fun insertCards(pair: CardPair) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.insert(pair)
    }

    fun deleteCards(pair: CardPair) = viewModelScope.launch {
        repository.deleteCard(pair)
    }
}

class WordViewModelFactory(private val repository:CardPairRepository) : ViewModelProvider.Factory {
    override fun <T : ViewModel> create(modelClass: Class<T>): T {
        if (modelClass.isAssignableFrom(CardViewmodel::class.java)) {
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            return CardViewmodel(repository) as T
        }
        throw IllegalArgumentException("Unknown ViewModel class")
    }
}
```

CardListAdapter.kt

```
class CardListAdapter : ListAdapter<CardPair,CardListAdapter.WordViewHolder>(WordsComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WordViewHolder {
        return WordViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WordViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val current = getItem(position)
        val current1 = getItem(position)
        holder.bind(current.front,current1.back)
    }

    class WordViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        private val wordItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        private val deftext: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1)

        fun bind(text: String?,text1: String?) {
            wordItemView.text = text
            deftext.text=text1
        }

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): WordViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, parent, false)
                return WordViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class WordsComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CardPair>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem:CardPair, newItem:CardPair): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem:CardPair, newItem:CardPair): Boolean {
            return oldItem.front == newItem.front && oldItem.back==newItem.back
        }
    }
}
```

The repository class is formed as follows

```
class CardPairRepository(private val cardPairDao: CardPairDao) {

    // Room executes all queries on a separate thread.
    // Observed Flow will notify the observer when the data has changed.
    val allWords: Flow<List<CardPair>> = cardPairDao.getAlphabetizedWords()

    // By default Room runs suspend queries off the main thread, therefore, we don't need to
    // implement anything else to ensure we're not doing long running database work
    // off the main thread.
    @Suppress("RedundantSuspendModifier")
    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun insert(pair: CardPair) {
        cardPairDao.insertWord(pair)
    }

    @WorkerThread
    suspend fun deleteCard(pair: CardPair){
        cardPairDao.deleteWord(pair)
    }
}
```

The data class that is used in setting up Room Database

```
@Entity(tableName = "word_table")
data class CardPair(
    @PrimaryKey @ColumnInfo(name = "front") val front: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "back") val back: String
)
```

The interface CardPairDao.kt

```
@Dao
interface CardPairDao {

    @Query("SELECT * FROM word_table ORDER BY front ASC, back ASC")
    fun getAlphabetizedWords(): Flow<List<CardPair>>

    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertWord(pair: CardPair)

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteWord(pair: CardPair)

}
```

The room database class is shown below
CardRoomDatabase.kt

```
@Database(entities = [CardPair::class], version = 2, exportSchema = true)
abstract class CardRoomDatabase : RoomDatabase() {

    abstract fun cardPairDao(): CardPairDao

    private class WordDatabaseCallback(
        private val scope: CoroutineScope
    ) : Callback() {

        override fun onCreate(db: SupportSQLiteDatabase) {
            super.onCreate(db)
            INSTANCE?.let { database ->
                scope.launch {
                    var wordDao = database.cardPairDao()

                    wordDao.getAlphabetizedWords()

                }
            }
        }
    }
    companion object {
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE:CardRoomDatabase? = null

        fun getDatabase(
            context: Context,
            scope: CoroutineScope
        ):CardRoomDatabase {
            // if the INSTANCE is not null, then return it,
            // if it is, then create the database
            return INSTANCE ?: synchronized(this) {
                val instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                    context.applicationContext,
                    CardRoomDatabase::class.java,
                    "word_database"
                )
                    .addCallback(WordDatabaseCallback(scope))
                    .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                    .build()
                INSTANCE = instance
                // return instance
                instance
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you link the repository?

Comment: I will edit and add repository class

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you provided, it looks like you are setting the click listener on an ImageView in a layout that is not part of the RecyclerView's layout.

To fix this issue, you can set the click listener on the ImageView inside the onBindViewHolder method of your RecyclerView adapter

Comment: Yeah you are right imageview is not directly the part of secondActivity's xml . How do you propose me to use click listener in onBindViewHolder method?

Answer (score 0):

Just edit the Adapter class like this and it will work -

```
class CardListAdapter : ListAdapter<CardPair,CardListAdapter.WordViewHolder>(WordsComparator()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): WordViewHolder {
        return WordViewHolder.create(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: WordViewHolder, position: Int) {
        val currentItem = getItem(position)

        holder.wordItemView.text = currentItem.front
        holder.deftext.text = currentItem.back

        holder.imageDelete.setOnClickListener {

             // Call the delete() method on your CardViewmodel to delete the CardPair from the database
             cardViewmodel.deleteCards(currentItem)

             // Notify the adapter that the data has changed
             adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position)

        }
    }

    class WordViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
        val wordItemView: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView)
        val deftext: TextView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.text1)
        val imageDelete = viewitemViewfindViewById<ImageView>(R.id.imageDelete)

        companion object {
            fun create(parent: ViewGroup): WordViewHolder {
                val view: View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(R.layout.recyclerview, parent, false)
                return WordViewHolder(view)
            }
        }
    }

    class WordsComparator : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<CardPair>() {
        override fun areItemsTheSame(oldItem:CardPair, newItem:CardPair): Boolean {
            return oldItem === newItem
        }

        override fun areContentsTheSame(oldItem:CardPair, newItem:CardPair): Boolean {
            return oldItem.front == newItem.front && oldItem.back==newItem.back
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In this I assumed, you're passing reference of view model to adapter but if you don't want to pass the reference then you can simply pass an callback function in constructor and get callback in your activity to simply run the delete code their.